# Adding vendor directory to heroku application

Tags: php, heroku

I have created and deployed a php app on heroku, but loading vendor is not working from config.php file. Checkout following...

**config.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

**index.php**

```
include('config/config.php');
```

**Directory structure**

```
config
--config.php
index.php
vendor
```

Its working on localhost but when i try to run after deploying to heroku, i get following error...

```
Warning: require_once(/app/config/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/config/config.php on line 10 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/app/config/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/config/config.php on line 10
```

Please help, i have tried google for an answer, but no luck. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that works on localhost. `__DIR__` points to the directory the current file is in, so in your case, that's `config/`, meaning you're including `config/vendor/autoload.php`.

You want a relative path instead:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```